# copying data from sap to excel

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

```
Sub invoicenumber1()

 Dim SAPGUIAuto     As Object                            '
    Dim SAPApplication As Object                            '
    Dim Connection     As Object                            '
    Dim session        As Object


Set SAPGUIAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set objGui = SAPGUIAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
Set session = objConn.Children(0)
Dim selectedcountry As String

 
selectedcountry = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nvl02"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLIKP-VBELN").Text = selectedcountry
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLIKP-VBELN").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[30]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[0]").pressButton "&FIND"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtLVC_S_SEA-STRING").Text = "invoice"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtLVC_S_SEA-STRING").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[18]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtVBUK-VBELN").caretPosition = 10

End Sub
```

[image]

i want to copy text from sap to excel please help me with the given code

i am new to this vba

i want to copy text from this line (session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtVBUK-VBELN").caretPosition = 10)

Comment: What about using `session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtVBUK-VBELN").text` ? You might want to look [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/5c2e0824d7d9411ea412239076b663a3.html?version=760.01&locale=en-US),

Comment: tq u so much its working fine

Answer (score 0):

add a watch to this (select code in VBA editor and right click -> Add watch) "(session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtVBUK-VBELN")" then you can see all attributes and you can use them as you want